# Youtube Data API V3 Refresh Access Token in Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, youtube

I'm currently trying to get my refresh access tokens. However, the way that I'm currently trying to do it produces an error in the indicated line. Does anyone have some insight on this?

```
app.get '/youtube_auth' do
            client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
            auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
            auth_client.update!(
                :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
                :redirect_uri => "https://0bba4895.ngrok.io/youtube_auth",
                :additional_parameters => {
                    "access_type" => "offline",         # offline access
                    "approval_prompt" => "force",
                    "include_granted_scopes" => "true"  # incremental auth
                }
            )
            if request['code'] == nil
                auth_uri = auth_client.authorization_uri.to_s
                redirect auth_uri
            else
                auth_client.code = request['code']
                auth_client.fetch_access_token!  # THIS IS CAUSING THE ERROR
                auth_client.client_secret = nil
                session[:credentials] = auth_client.to_json # set my session 
                redirect '/oauth_done'
            end
        end
```

The specific error I'm getting is `{ "error" : "invalid_request", "error_description" : "Parameter not allowed for this message type: access_type" }`

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: I've never used this library before, so please bear in mind that the following information is based on 5 minute's googling... `Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets` is deprecated; the documentation states you should migrate to using the (very similar) [google-auth-library](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby).

Comment: Take a look at the [shared examples](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/37ed189b2e5165243918fcde127ebe323e9a06b5/spec/googleauth/apply_auth_examples.rb) for the [user refresh spec](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/37ed189b2e5165243918fcde127ebe323e9a06b5/spec/googleauth/user_refresh_spec.rb), if the gem's documentation is unclear.

Comment: @TomLord Hm it seems like they need to update their site as well because I've been following their tutorials/guides on their site...